# Bottom Navigation Bar in flutter not switching screens on tapping on the tabs

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

With reference to [Hans Muller's article](https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386) on creating a fading effect and using bottom navigation bar in Flutter, the below code doesn't switch screens when tapped. It stays on the same screen i.e. homescreen even after I tap on the different bottom navigation bar items.

Below is the snippet of my code which is mostly copy of the code in the article. I can't seem to understand why the screen transition does not work when i tap on the navigation bar buttons.

```
class NavigationRouterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationRouterScreenState createState() => _NavigationRouterScreenState();
}

class _NavigationRouterScreenState extends State<NavigationRouterScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin<NavigationRouterScreen> {
  List<Key> _destinationKeys;
  List<AnimationController> _faders;
  AnimationController _hide;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _faders = allDestinations.map<AnimationController>((Destination destination) {
      return AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    }).toList();
    _faders[_currentIndex].value = 1.0;
    _destinationKeys = List<Key>.generate(allDestinations.length, (int index) => GlobalKey()).toList();
    _hide = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: kThemeAnimationDuration);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (AnimationController controller in _faders)
      controller.dispose();
    _hide.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool _handleScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification.depth == 0) {
      if (notification is UserScrollNotification) {
        final UserScrollNotification userScroll = notification;
        switch (userScroll.direction) {
          case ScrollDirection.forward:
            _hide.forward();
            break;
          case ScrollDirection.reverse:
            _hide.reverse();
            break;
          case ScrollDirection.idle:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  Color colorByIndex(int index) {
    return index == _currentIndex ? Color(0xFF323255) : Colors.grey;
  }

  List<Widget> allChildren() {
    var listofitems = allDestinations.map((Destination destination) {
      final Widget view = FadeTransition(
        opacity: _faders[destination.index].drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)),
        child: KeyedSubtree(
          key: _destinationKeys[destination.index],
          child: DestinationView(
            destination: destination,
            onNavigation: () {
              _hide.forward();
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
      if (destination.index == _currentIndex) {
        _faders[destination.index].forward();
        return view;
      } else {
        _faders[destination.index].reverse();
        if (_faders[destination.index].isAnimating) {
          return IgnorePointer(child: view);
        }
        return Offstage(child: view);
      }
    }).toList();
    return listofitems;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: _handleScrollNotification,
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: ClipRect(
          child: SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: _hide,
            axisAlignment: -1.0,
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: _currentIndex,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              items: allDestinations.map((Destination destination) {
                return BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    destination.iconPath,
                    height: 24.0,
                    width: 24.0,
                    color: colorByIndex(destination.index),
                  ),
                  title: Text(destination.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11.0,
                      color: colorByIndex(destination.index),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: allChildren(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class DestinationView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DestinationView({ Key key, this.destination, this.onNavigation }) : super(key: key);

  final Destination destination;
  final VoidCallback onNavigation;

  @override
  _DestinationViewState createState() => _DestinationViewState();
}

class _DestinationViewState extends State<DestinationView> {

  Route _registerRoutesWithParameters(RouteSettings settings) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (context) {
        switch(settings.name) {
          case RouteConstants.home:
            print(settings.name);
            return HomeScreen(destination: widget.destination);
          case RouteConstants.stats:
            return StatsScreen(destination: widget.destination);
          case RouteConstants.profile:
            return ProfileScreen(destination: widget.destination);
          default:
            return HomeScreen(destination: widget.destination);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      observers: <NavigatorObserver>[
        ViewNavigatorObserver(widget.onNavigation),
      ],
      onGenerateRoute: _registerRoutesWithParameters,
    );
  }
}

class ViewNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  ViewNavigatorObserver(this.onNavigation);

  final VoidCallback onNavigation;

  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    onNavigation();
  }
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    onNavigation();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code as follows:

```
    switch (widget.destination.index) {
          case 0:
            switch (settings.name) {
               case RouteConstants.home:
                 return HomeRootPage(destination: widget.destination);
               case RouteConstants.home_list:
                 return HomeListPage(destination: widget.destination);
               case RouteConstants.home_text:
                 return HomeTextPage(destination: widget.destination);
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            switch (settings.name) {
               case RouteConstants.stats:
                 return StatsRootPage(destination: widget.destination);
               case RouteConstants.stats_list:
                 return StatsListPage(destination: widget.destination);
               case RouteConstants.stats_text:
                 return StatsTextPage(destination: widget.destination);
            }
            break;
}
```